# Specify an argument for one resource create by a loop - Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

It's possible to use a variable to add a non-default argument for a resource that is being created with a count loop?

For example:

```
resource "resource" "example" {
   count = length(var.resources)
   name = var.resources[count.index]
}
```

Where var.resources is:

```
["X", "Y", ...]
```

And now, I have the necessity to add and specific argument for one of this resources.

```
Resource "Y" will need a specific argument like " description = example"
```

It's possible? which is the best option? Use for_each instead of count and map var?

Comment: Using `for_each` instead of `count` with a map is the easiest way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reorganize your `var.resources` into a map:

```
variable "resources" {
  default = {
       "X" = {}
       "Y" = {description = "x description"}
  } 
}
```

then:

```
resource "resource" "example" {
   for_each    = var.resources
   name        = each.key
   description = lookup(each.value, "description", null)
}
```